# Accumulo cluster in AWS with s3 not really stable

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-zookeeper, accumulo

we're running an accumulo cluster on AWS using s3 instead of hdfs, once in a while we cannot log in the shell anymore. We tried different cluster settings with the same result, sometimes something breaks and we're not able to work with it anymore. I was wondering if using s3 could cause some kind of problems.

This is the log that leads to a WARN : There are no tablet
 servers: check that zookeeper and accumulo are running.

We cannot see very useful informations neither on the logs or on the internet'

Any ideas?

> 2016-04-13 14:57:56,587 [client.ClientConfiguration] WARN : Found no
>   client.conf in default paths. Using default client configuration
>   values. 2016-04-13 14:57:56,591 [client.ClientConfiguration] WARN :
>   Found no client.conf in default paths. Using default client
>   configuration values. 2016-04-13 14:57:58,421 [fs.EmrFileSystem] INFO
>   : Consistency disabled, using
>   com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem as filesystem
>   implementation 2016-04-13 14:57:59,018 [amazonaws.latency] INFO :
>   ServiceName=[Amazon S3], StatusCode=[200],
>   ServiceEndpoint=[test-accumulo.s3.amazonaws.com],
>   AWSRequestID=[null], HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0,
>   HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=0, RequestCount=1,
>   HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, ResponseProcessingTime=[1.219],
>   ClientExecuteTime=[347.47], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[2.211],
>   HttpRequestTime=[247.724], RequestSigningTime=[38.773],
>   HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[32.567],  2016-04-13 14:57:59,023
>   [s3n.S3NativeFileSystem] INFO : listStatus
>   s3://test-accumulo/instance_id with recursive false 2016-04-13
>   14:57:59,039 [amazonaws.latency] INFO : ServiceName=[Amazon S3],
>   StatusCode=[200],
>   ServiceEndpoint=[test-accumulo.s3.amazonaws.com],
>   AWSRequestID=[null], HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0,
>   HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, RequestCount=1,
>   HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, ResponseProcessingTime=[0.007],
>   ClientExecuteTime=[14.182], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[1.802],
>   HttpRequestTime=[12.222], RequestSigningTime=[0.915],
>   HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[8.026],  2016-04-13 14:57:59,165
>   [amazonaws.latency] INFO : ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSErrorCode=[404
>   Not Found], StatusCode=[404],
>   ServiceEndpoint=[test-accumulo.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com],
>   Exception=[com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Not
>   Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not
>   Found; Request ID: 5AF8579AA42CF9BE), S3 Extended Request ID:
>   hOWVSRu+ukai8IMHUvBbnQzGp3SvhXgHRiqzIzGrwJKhiJLRTM3+i4JiawJg7eFH1vk4mbPrKW8=],
>   AWSRequestID=[5AF8579AA42CF9BE], HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0,
>   HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, RequestCount=1, Exception=1,
>   HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, ClientExecuteTime=[125.731],
>   HttpClientSendRequestTime=[1.991], HttpRequestTime=[118.59],
>   RequestSigningTime=[0.276], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[36.485], 
>   2016-04-13 14:57:59,309 [amazonaws.latency] INFO : ServiceName=[Amazon
>   S3], StatusCode=[200],
>   ServiceEndpoint=[test-accumulo.s3.amazonaws.com],
>   AWSRequestID=[4EA22D07E9553B58], HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0,
>   HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=2, RequestCount=1,
>   HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, ResponseProcessingTime=[24.253],
>   ClientExecuteTime=[141.373], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.727],
>   HttpRequestTime=[110.592], RequestSigningTime=[0.358],
>   HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[104.977],  2016-04-13 14:57:59,313
>   [cse.CSEUtils] INFO : Cannot get jobflow Id from
>   extraInstanceData.json. Setting jobflowId = Unknown. 2016-04-13
>   14:57:59,329 [client.ClientConfiguration] WARN : Found no client.conf
>   in default paths. Using default client configuration values.
>   2016-04-13 14:57:59,530 [trace.DistributedTrace] INFO : SpanReceiver
>   org.apache.accumulo.tracer.ZooTraceClient was loaded successfully.
>   2016-04-13 14:57:59,577 [impl.ServerClient] WARN : There are no tablet
>   servers: check that zookeeper and accumulo are running.

Comment: This might be related to a wrong comunication with zookeeper. I can see this in the logs: WARN: Saw (possibly) transient exception communicating with ZooKeeper
wil try to use ip addresses instead dns

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would expect that running Accumulo with S3 would result in problems. Even though S3 has a FileSystem implementation, it does not behave like a normal file system. Some examples of the differences are that operations we would expect to be atomic are not atomic in S3, exceptions may mean different things than we expect, and we assume our view of files and their metadata is consistent rather than the eventual consistency S3 provides.

It's possible these issues could be mitigated if we made some modifications to the Accumulo code, but as far as I know no one has tried running Accumulo on S3 to figure out the problems and whether those could be fixed or not.

Answer (score 0):

we also trying to use accumulo with s3, thanks @billie for giving us these important thoughts, about "operations we would expect to be atomic are not atomic in S3", can you give us some example? perhaps something like committing WALs?

about consistency, yes, we saw that EMRFS provides [Consistent View](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-plan-consistent-view.html), so, to use this "Consistent View" will solve the consistency problem or?

and in the Consistent View page, it says, consistency will be a problem only by **update (overwrite put) and delete** operations, is this possible to block request on the tablets during filesystem update and delete operations a little bit longer (let it offline shortly), to avoid consistency problem? maybe worth to make this option as a config property?

btw... the state >

> issues could be mitigated if we made some modifications to the Accumulo code

really make us worried... is it not possible to solve the problem? they can only be mitigated?

Thanks a lot.